# Laravel Image Intervention resize quality loss

Tags: image, laravel, image-resizing, intervention

In my Laravel web-application I make use of the [Intervention Image library](http://image.intervention.io/). I'm saving three versions of the uploaded image: `'original'`, `'500_auto'` and a custom size image.

```php
$image = Image::make(Input::file('file');

// Save the orignal image
$image->save($folder . 'original.' . $extension);

// Save 500_auto image
$image->resize(500, null, function($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
$image->save($folder . '500_auto.' . $extension, 100);

// Check if size is set
if (isset($config->images->width) && isset($config->images->height)) {
    // Assign values
    $width  = $config->images->width;
    $height = $config->images->height;
    // Create the custom thumb
    $image->resize($width, $height, function($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });
    $image->save($folder . $width . '_' . $height . '.' . $extension, 100);
}
```

The driver of Intervention is set in the config as `'gd'`:

```
'driver' => 'gd'
```

This is the image I'm uploading: [original.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgOFC.jpg)

[image: Original image]

And this is the result from the custom thumb with the config settings set to exact the original sizes (1800 x 586): [1800_586.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvuSG.jpg)

[image: Resized image]

As you can see the second image there is a lot of quality loss in the resized image. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're first resizing the image to a small format, then you take the small image and resize that to the original size again. If you reverse the order, you'll go from original size -> original size -> small size instead.

Personally, I usually prefer to redo the `Image::make()` call for every new image, just to make sure I don't screw something like this up along the way.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Very logical, it was resizing to the small version and resizing to 1800x586 after that. I updated the method by recalling the Image::make() before every resizing, just like you mentioned.

Comment: Good line to create new `Image::make()` for every resize. That was the reason which causes the blurred image in resize function.

Answer (score 10):

You can use "backup()" method to save the object's status and "reset()" method to return back to backup state:

```
// create an image
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');

// backup status
$img->backup();

// perform some modifications
$img->resize(320, 240);
$img->invert();
$img->save('public/small.jpg');

// reset image (return to backup state)
$img->reset();

// perform other modifications
$img->resize(640, 480);
$img->invert();
$img->save('public/large.jpg');
```

more info on this page:
http://image.intervention.io/api/reset